# Gentoo@neo wget problem

Tags: linux, networking, http, wget, gentoo

I have a neo freerunner, on which i'm installing gentoo. I need to run *layman -S* but it fails to download *repositories.xml* from `www.gentoo.org`. When i try to download the latter with wget it fails also: the connection is established (syn is acked and the http GET is sent), but there is no response from the peer.

But i can download other pages (i've tried ya.ru and google) with wget, so i assume the connection is alive. The ping to www.gentoo.org is ok as well.

Can you please direct me where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

on the router machine did the job.